# 'React native run android' stops just after start the app in emulator

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator, adb

I am trying to run react-native run-android but in 1st project, it is working perfectly, but in other it automatically stops after starting intent. I have also tried `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` but its not working for my project named, "basicredux" I have attached the screenshot , hope it will help you to help me to solve this problem.

I have also tried the solution in 
['React native run android' stop immediatelly after start the app in emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718850/react-native-run-android-stop-immediatelly-after-start-the-app-in-emulator)
But it is not working.
in my first project which i created about 1 month ago, it is working perfectly, but not with any of my new projects.
Sorry for not disclosing my first project name.

Working perfectly on my this 1 month old project :

[image: Working perfectly on my this 1 month old project]

Not working on this project or any new Projects:

[image: Not working on this project or any new Projects]

Attaching the Log Cat :

[image: Log Cat]

Comment: Doesn't a new project work?

Comment: yes I tried new projects, but it is same for all new projects, but for old project it is working well @hongdevelop

Comment: Did you check the Log Cat when you ran on the Android studio?

Comment: Yeah try running logcat in one screen and run-android on another

Comment: wait a minute i am attaching the logcat screenshot @hongdevelop

Comment: go to android folder and run ./gradlew cleanBuildCache and after this run your project again. This might help

Comment: I tried ./gradlew cleanBuildCache but it also didn't helped me @amitsin6h

Comment: Thanks to both of you for helping me... @hongdevelop

Comment: @kvadityaaz I'm glad I found the problem. I hope you can experience a lot of things through React Native and help you develop React Native.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that after running `react-native start` along with `react-native run-android` in same project directory, the 'react-native run-android' stops but on editing the App.js file I can see the changes, only by clicking the reload button from the emulator screen or, `ctrl + M` then `reload`

**Solution**

Run `react-native start` in one terminal
then `react-native run-android` in another tab of the terminal
then `ctrl + M` then `reload` in emulator devices, or shake and reload in real devices.

[image: screenshot]